# No animation with show

Tags: jquery

Here is my code that is supposed to show / hide `#id_admirer_or_model_0` and `#id_admirer_or_model_1` which are `div`s containing form fields:

```
<script>
    $( function() {

        $( "#id_admirer_or_model_0" ).click( function() {
            $( ".model_form_fields" ).hide( "slow" );
        } );

        $( "#id_admirer_or_model_1" ).click( function() {
            $( ".model_form_fields" ).show( "slow" );
        } );
    } )
</script>
```

And here is the code from http://api.jquery.com/show/ :

```
<script>
    $( "button" ).click(function() {
      $( "p" ).show( "slow" );
    });
</script>
```

Why is the jquery code correctly animating the showing of the 'p', while mine doesn't show animation at all and abruptly displays the divs?

UPDATE:

Html code:

```
// Trigger
<div class="fieldWrapper">

    <label for="id_admirer_or_model_0">What type of member are you
        ?:</label>
    <ul id="id_admirer_or_model">
        <li><label for="id_admirer_or_model_0"><input type="radio" name="admirer_or_model"
                                                      value="admirer" required
                                                      id="id_admirer_or_model_0"/>
            Admirer</label>

        </li>
        <li><label for="id_admirer_or_model_1"><input type="radio" name="admirer_or_model"
                                                      value="model" required
                                                      id="id_admirer_or_model_1"/>
            Model</label>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>


// Target
<div class="model_form_fields">
    <div class="fieldWrapper">

        <label for="">What is your model
            category:</label>
        <ul id="id_model_categories">
            <li><label for="id_model_categories_0"><input type="checkbox" name="model_categories"
                                                          value="cat0"
                                                          id="id_model_categories_0"/>
                cat0</label>

            </li>
            <li><label for="id_model_categories_1"><input type="checkbox" name="model_categories"
                                                          value="cat1"
                                                          id="id_model_categories_1"/>
                cat1</label>

            </li>
            <li><label for="id_model_categories_2"><input type="checkbox" name="model_categories"
                                                          value="cat2" id="id_model_categories_2"/>
                cat2</label>

            </li>
            <li><label for="id_model_categories_3"><input type="checkbox" name="model_categories"
                                                          value="cat3" id="id_model_categories_3"/>
                cat3</label>

            </li>
            <li><label for="id_model_categories_4"><input type="checkbox" name="model_categories"
                                                          value="cat4" id="id_model_categories_4"/>
                cat4</label>

            </li>
            <li><label for="id_model_categories_5"><input type="checkbox" name="model_categories"
                                                          value="cat5"
                                                          id="id_model_categories_5"/>
                cat5</label>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Initial CSS:

```
.model_form_fields {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: are you loading elements (#id_admirer_or_model_0 or ...) using ajax or by using javascript dynamically?

Comment: Could you show us the html as well?

Comment: Can you post your html code as well? To me, it sounds like a missing tag.

check this-> https://jsfiddle.net/6uudt057/

Comment: Have you check by using css display: none for your class .model_form_fields?

Comment: Updated with html

Comment: I haven't found id_admirer_or_model_0 & id_admirer_or_model_1 div in your updated html code? Will you check & update the html code again?

Comment: I do not see #id_admirer_or_model_0 or #id_admirer_or_model_1 elements within your html code. Is this is what you are trying to do? https://jsfiddle.net/6uudt057/1/

Comment: Added html trigger

Answer (score 0):

try by increase in time, if not work than show your html

```
  $("button").click(function(){
        $("p").hide(1000);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this in the jquery api web site : http://api.jquery.com/show/ :

*Note: This method may cause performance issues, especially when used on many elements. If you're encountering such issues, use performance testing tools to determine whether this method is causing them. Moreover, this method can cause problems with responsive layouts if the display value differs at different viewport sizes.*

`$( ".model_form_fields" )` selector is selecting too many elements in DOM.

Comment: but it doesn't specify that the animation is disabled automatically in case of many elements

Answer (score 0):

You have miss semicolon in the last line of function before script closing tag. Here is updated code.

```
<script>
    $( function() {

        $( "#id_admirer_or_model_0" ).click( function() {
            $( ".model_form_fields" ).hide( "slow" );
        } );

        $( "#id_admirer_or_model_1" ).click( function() {
            $( ".model_form_fields" ).show( "slow" );
        } );
    } );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you want:

```
<script>
$( function() {

        $( "#id_admirer_or_model_0" ).click( function() {
            $( ".model_form_fields" ).hide( "slow" );
        } );

        $( "#id_admirer_or_model_1" ).click( function() {
            $( ".model_form_fields" ).show( "slow" );
        } );
    } );
</script>
```

CSS:

```
.model_form_fields {
  display: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="fieldWrapper">

    <label for="id_admirer_or_model_0">What type of member are you
        ?:</label>
    <ul id="id_admirer_or_model">
        <li><label for="id_admirer_or_model_0"><input type="radio" name="admirer_or_model"
                                                      value="admirer" required
                                                      id="id_admirer_or_model_0"/>
            Admirer</label>

        </li>
        <li><label for="id_admirer_or_model_1"><input type="radio" name="admirer_or_model"
                                                      value="model" required
                                                      id="id_admirer_or_model_1"/>
            Model</label>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>


// Target
<div class="model_form_fields">
    <div class="fieldWrapper">

        <label for="">What is your model
            category:</label>
        <ul id="id_model_categories">
            <li><label for="id_model_categories_0"><input type="checkbox" name="model_categories"
                                                          value="cat0"
                                                          id="id_model_categories_0"/>
                cat0</label>

            </li>
            <li><label for="id_model_categories_1"><input type="checkbox" name="model_categories"
                                                          value="cat1"
                                                          id="id_model_categories_1"/>
                cat1</label>

            </li>
            <li><label for="id_model_categories_2"><input type="checkbox" name="model_categories"
                                                          value="cat2" id="id_model_categories_2"/>
                cat2</label>

            </li>
            <li><label for="id_model_categories_3"><input type="checkbox" name="model_categories"
                                                          value="cat3" id="id_model_categories_3"/>
                cat3</label>

            </li>
            <li><label for="id_model_categories_4"><input type="checkbox" name="model_categories"
                                                          value="cat4" id="id_model_categories_4"/>
                cat4</label>

            </li>
            <li><label for="id_model_categories_5"><input type="checkbox" name="model_categories"
                                                          value="cat5"
                                                          id="id_model_categories_5"/>
                cat5</label>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/eq7vtLum/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#id_admirer_or_model_0" ).click(function(){
    $( "li" ).first().show( "fast", function showNext() {
      $( this ).next( "li" ).show( "fast", showNext );
    });
  });

  $("#id_admirer_or_model_1" ).click(function(){
    $( "li" ).last().hide( "fast", function hidePrev() {
      $( this ).prev( "li" ).hide( "fast", hidePrev );
    });
  });
});
```

```css
li {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="model_form_fields">
  <div class="fieldWrapper">
    <label for="">What is your model category:</label>
    <ul id="id_model_categories">
      <li>
        <label for="id_model_categories_0">
          <input type="checkbox" name="model_categories" value="cat0"  id="id_model_categories_0"/> cat0
        </label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="id_model_categories_1">
          <input type="checkbox" name="model_categories" value="cat1" id="id_model_categories_1"/>
            cat1
        </label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="id_model_categories_2">
          <input type="checkbox" name="model_categories" value="cat2" id="id_model_categories_2"/>
            cat2
        </label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="id_model_categories_3">
          <input type="checkbox" name="model_categories" value="cat3" id="id_model_categories_3"/>
            cat3
        </label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="id_model_categories_4">
          <input type="checkbox" name="model_categories" value="cat4" id="id_model_categories_4"/>
            cat4
        </label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="id_model_categories_5">
          <input type="checkbox" name="model_categories" value="cat5" id="id_model_categories_5"/>
            cat5
        </label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>


<button id="id_admirer_or_model_0">Show it</button>
<button id="id_admirer_or_model_1">Hide it</button>
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I added your code to a fiddle and to me, animation is there.

```
Fiddle,
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6uudt057/2/

What am I missing?